# Unable to create Angular 2 SPA template app having meddled with Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have been learning Angular and using `dotnet new angular` to create new applications.  I tried to upgrade the app created from the template to Angular 4 before finding out that it completely breaks it.  I did try rolling back to 2 without success and now I find that creating a new application from scratch using the SPA template results in the following error.  I have made no code changes prior to hitting Ctrl+F5.

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ html: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RenderToStringResult | RedirectResult | PromiseLike'.
>     Type '{ html: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike'.
>       Property 'then' is missing in type '{ html: string; }'.

The offending file seems to be boot-server.ts and in particular the below section of code.

```
return requestZone.run<Promise<string>>(() => platform.serializeModule(AppModule)).then(html => {
        resolve({ html: html });
    }, reject);
```

**Update**

It is the debug in VS2017 that is the issue.  `dotnet run` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not from VS2017, but a package that has been updated, and based on package.json configuration it will be updated on `npm install` or `yarn` ( or when trying to publish if you check the csproj configuration), the package with the issue is : `"aspnet-prerendering": "2.0.4",` that just been released 3-4 hours ago, using `2.0.3` solves this problem.

try with `npm install aspnet-prerendering@2.0.3`

Most likely this issue will be fixed in a matter of hours.

`dotnet run` doesn't run `npm` tasks thats why it works with files already in your wwwroot folder.

*Update*

a new update to package has been pushed to fix this issue `2.0.5`
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/918

Comment: I am following the thread on [git](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/918) and that has just come up.  I have downgraded in `package.json` but that hasn't helped so will try cli.  Many thanks.

Comment: have you tried to clean all `node_modules` and reinstall them?

Comment: Just travelling.  Will do a full clean and install with 2.0.5 when I get a chance.